# Webdriver wont click on a second link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make a bot using selenium, but I'm having trouble with my bot going to a different part of a website. In my code, my driver successfully goes to nike.com ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9fW.jpg)), then successfully clicks and loads a different link within Nike (clicks circled area in ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9fW.jpg)) and goes to ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Xfp.jpg))). Then, my problems begin here, I try to click and load a different link ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Xfp.jpg)) but my driver does nothing. I know my driver found the second link because if I print out 'second.text' then I get the correct text ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vspz0.png))...

I am still new to selenium and I pretty much don't know what I am doing. Any help would be helpful.
Thank you.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

        driver.get("https://www.nike.com/men")

        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        first = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="prl3-sm")
        first.click()

        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        second = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='a[class="JSftBPEZ"]')
        #print(second.text)
        second.click()
```

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console/terminal?

Comment: I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Also, I just figured out my problem. My webdriver was closing chrome wayyyy too fast so it didnt have enough time to load. If I have another question relating to this should I make another post? @furas

Comment: and I get error on first click - maybe because I have to accept cookies before this element will be clickable. Sometimes it may find object but it can't click it because it is hidden behind other object

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it.
Through Javascript click its getting clicked.

here is the code to click on second link.

```
second = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='a[class="JSftBPEZ"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",second)
```

BTW you may need to define xpath properly. Example the second link pointing to  6 elements. But anyway through Javascript sclick it would click the 1st option

Comment: My problem now is that webdriver is closing the chrome window too fast. I tried your code and it does the same thing as my code (close chrome too fast on my computer), so for now it seems correct. Thank you

Comment: put some wait time or comment out driver.close  option so that it wont close the browser or add a print statement after 2nd click and execute with debug option with debug point on print statement. it would stop there. But with my code its clicking. i have tested it

Comment: How would I do that? Is it fine if I use  implicitly_wait or sleep from the time library?

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(20)

Comment: i have give 20 , you can given as much time you want

Comment: Did not do anything for me. I increased the time to 20 seconds for all implicitly_wait and added another implicitly_wait after second.click, but my program still exits too quickly.  I also don't have any driver.close call, and i just tried to place a debug point on the print statement and my code still just exited from my chrome window.

Comment: did print statement print

Comment: also try using time.sleep(5) after second click. and declare import time on top where you mentioned other import statements

Comment: So I just retried the debugger and it worked (I guess I clicked run instead of the debugger). Im gonna try the time.sleep also

Comment: The time.sleep(5) worked well. Thank you so much !